# This webpage has a redirect loop php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, post

On my index page I have a link to my admin_login.php page with this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location:admin_login.php");
exit();
 }

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["password"]);

include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($existCount==1) {
echo 'Na Na Na Na';
exit();
}

?>
```

On the admin_login.php page I have

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"])) {

 $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_POST["manager"]);
 $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_POST["password"]);
 include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND     password='$password' LIMIT 1");
 $existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if($existCount==1) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$id=$row["id"];
}
$_SESSION["id"]=$id;
$_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;
$_SESSION["password"]=$password;
header("location: index.php");
exit();
   } else { 
echo ' That info is incorrect , try again <a href="index.php"> Click Here </a>';
exit();
    }
    }
    ?>
```

i am using a admin panel to login the admin for furhter procedure, but it shows me the eroor of redirect loop .

Comment: the mysql interface is deprecated and vulnerable to SQL injection.  consider migrating to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) asap.  also consider not blindly stripping characters from passwords that is a super bad idea.

Comment: $_SESSION["manager"] is making the prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it occurs due to a logic error (Redirection Looping....)

suppose at **index.php**  `$_SESSION["manager"]` is not set  due to following code

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location:admin_login.php");
exit();
 }
```

it goes to `admin_login.php` at there  due to following code

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
```

it goes to `index.php`

**update** hmmmmm..........

**Warning:** mysql_* are Depricated...

**Soln to your question**

it may depend on your logic ....

i may say one....

let me choose loginPage.php (you can have the index.php) be the admins gateway
Let the code be

```
function LoginChecker()
{ //Returns 0=Not,1=ok,2=Fraud

$hashCode= md5("of your Security Factor"); //something for better security


if(isset($_SESSION["is_LoggedIn_as_Admin"]))
{
if(isset($_SESSION["Logged_Admin_HASH"]))
{
if($_SESSION["Logged_Admin_HASH"]==$hashCode) //something for better security
{
//its login time have your Code Goes 
 return 1;
}
else
{ return 2;}
}
else
{ return 2;}
}
else
{ return 0;}
}
```

Check like this more than a Redirect

```
if(LoginChecker()==1)
{
//Logged in
}
else
{
//Html Code to show LoginPage or E......
//include "Login.php"
}
```

Remind to set `$_SESSION["is_LoggedIn_as_Admin"] $_SESSION["Logged_Admin_HASH"]` at Login

Comment: @BîlålÇhådhår you need to set `$_SESSION["manager"]` to avoid the redirection.