# SESSION isset, redirect

Tags: php, redirect

This is my code for userslist.php. I put it above the head of this page so if this link is clicked, only admin can enter the page as filtered that is why I have redirections.

```
 session_start();

$loggedInfo['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];

if(
isset($loggedInfo['username']) && $loggedInfo['username']==="admin" &&
trim($loggedInfo['username']) != "guest"
)
{
header('Location: userslist.php');
}
else {
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
```

This is my php script and I got a problem with `redirecting`. On the `header(location ...)` when I changed it to echo true or false, the echo returns the value correctly. But when I put a redirect/location, it does say:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

Why is that? :(

Comment: Are you redirecting on same page ?

Comment: No.. Even if I'm in antoher page, it has an error like that.

Comment: what is your `userlist.php` code.because the code work perfectly without any error.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626998/this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-php

Comment: @Mahmood: Above is my code for userslist.php. I put it above the head of this page so if this link is clicked, only admin can enter the page as filtered that is why I have redirections.

Comment: You should place `exit()` right after `header('location')`

Comment: @djay: yes, done. But This webpage has a redirect loop appears.

Comment: For testing purposes: replace `header('Location: userslist.php');` with `echo 'going to redirect to userlist'`  and `header('Location: ../index.php');` with `echo 'redirecting home'`. What does it say?

Comment: @djay: for redirecting home, it is blank.

Comment: What's the current location of your script? Where's that? In what folder?

Comment: I tried changing my `header location` to true or false, it works.. But for redirecting, it does not. location is in the php folder. index is outside php folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in top of the `userlist.php`.An try what you got

```
<?php session_start();
$loggedInfo['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($loggedInfo['username']) && $loggedInfo['username']!="admin"){

header('Location: ../index.php');
exit();
}else if(isset($loggedInfo['username']) && $loggedInfo['username']=="admin"){


?>
```

You page code here goes

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So strange that I can still enter userslist even if im a guest. :(

Comment: I don't think so.there is `&&` condition.Print the `user name` below the code.

Comment: After the `}`? if Inside the curly braces, still I can get inside the userslist page.

Comment: It still has a u r admin echo. :(

Comment: what is the value of session variable ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45247/discussion-between-cecil-and-mahmood-rehman)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably including this code in all pages. Thus on userslist.php it will also redirect to userslist.php. This causes permanent redirects, which is a redirect loop.

> This conclusion is however difficult to support without seeing all the code you are using.

Comment: Above is my code for userslist.php. I put it above the head of this page so if this link is clicked, only admin can enter the page as filtered that is why I have redirections.